# Bind code behind Resource file value to javascript confirm delete

Tags: .net, javascript

I would like to show Confirm alert on button click, but confirm message I would like to show from a global resource file? How do I do this?
Something like this.
 OnClientClick="return confirm('<%$ Resources:MfnWeb, ConfirmCloseAccount%>')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set OnClientClick as you suggested in the codebehind file, eg. in PageLoad event, or write a  element inside page head with a function 'customized' for each page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myResource()
  {
    return '<%$ Resources:MfnWeb, ConfirmCloseAccount %>';
  }
</script>
```

Then call this function in any javascript code you want.

Comment: I need to use only on Button ClientClick is there a way I can directly bind it in a Confirm alert? return confirm('<%$ Resources:MfnWeb, ConfirmCloseAccount%>')"

Comment: The problem is that you cannot use <%$ %> inside an attribute. What you can do is to set the funtcion on the codebehind file, or call 'return confirm(myResource())', or make a function that shows the confirmation.